# systemjs module in typeScript: XHR error

Tags: typescript, systemjs

### Error:  
GET http://localhost:63342/Dog.js 404 (Not Found)                                           
XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:63342/Dog.js

```
             <br/><br/>Here is my script in index.html.                                                                              <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.src.js"></script>

<script>
    // set our baseURL reference path
    System.config({
        baseURL: '.'
    });

    System.import('Dog.js').catch(console.log.bind(console));
</script>
```

Animal.ts

```
export class Animal {
    color: string;
    age: number;

    constructor(color: string, age:number) {
        this.color = color;
        this.age = age;
    }

    add(animal: Animal) {
        return new Animal(this.color + animal.color, this.age + animal.age);
    }
}
```

Dog.ts

```
import {Animal} from './Animal';

var animal1 = new Animal("red", 1);
var animal2 = new Animal("yellow", 2);
var animal3 = animal1.add(animal2);
console.log('Combine Two Animals' + animal3);
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

All of the above files are in the same folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your html to:

```
System.config({
    baseURL: '.'
});

System.defaultJSExtensions = true;

System.import('Dog').catch(console.log.bind(console));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. It helps. Could you please tell me why we need to add this line of code?

Comment: I am actually surprised that the Dog.js cannot be loaded. If I run your code it complains on loading Animal.js module and there is a reason for that. If you do not specify defaultJSExtensions flag then SystemJS will try to load all your modules with .js extension. But in typescript you define module Animal not Animal.js. Therefore it will not be found. To overcome that the above option is usually used (or the newer version using maps) see system.js configuration docs for more info: https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/config-api.md

Comment: @Amid: your solution also did the job! Many thanks. Puzzles me because the book I used didn't use it and thus therefor my code didn't work.
Hate it when code used in books aren't working! :-(